# How to make an entire bootstrap thumbnail clickable (for mobile and tablet)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, hover, thumbnails

Using Bootstrap3, I am trying to make a page with few thumbnails leading to different links.
I have figured out how to make hover effect with text and link but now I am confused how it can be used with mobile and tablet as there is no hover for those.

I am wondering how to make the entire thumbnail clickable?
and is it a good idea to make it so?

Here is a bootply link for you to see what I mean
http://www.bootply.com/OuUBXv4ope

Comment: I've tried this on mobile and the hover effect happens when you click on the image, so I think you needn't worry about that. But, if I may say, it could be difficult for some people to click on the tiny `open` button, so I suggest you could put in a bigger icon like [this](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/link/) in the center maybe.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Chinmayahd. That open button is just a place holder, which I would have made bigger. But now I am thinking of making the entire thumbnail clickable (like this http://enlisteddesign.com/our-work/ ).
Could anyone suggest I can I achieve this in Bootstrap?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Making the entire thumbnail clickable is a good idea in terms of user accessibility and in fact, easy to make.

According to your code:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <!-- Place the anchor tag here to cover both your caption and image -->
        <a href="#" class="">
            <div class="caption">
                <h4 class="">Thumbnail Headline</h4>
                <p class="">Lorem ipsum dolor
                </p>
            </div>
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/300/technics/1/" alt="..." class="">
        </a>
        <!-- Anchor tag ends covering both image and caption -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/jf5wQlQVGI)** *(The first 3 thumbnails)*

Comment: Thank you I Can Has Kittenz!
I will try it out now and get back soon. 

(Apology for not mentioning your name in the previous comment as I thought it was someone else)

Comment: Tried it. and it's working! :)
Thank you again "I Can Has Kittenz"!

Comment: Works like a charm on Bootstrap 4 too :-)